# Trouble Extracting Directory Name from Path

Tags: python

Let's say I have a path A.

A = /Users/myname/Documents/folder1

Within  folder1, there are folder2 and folder3, and within folder2 and folder3, there are files named "file.txt". I want to go through every subdirectory in folder1, and replace "file.txt" with "folder[#]_file.txt" (the name of the subdirectory + "file.txt").

I have the following code:

```
import os, sys

def main():
    path = "/Users/myname/Documents/folder1/"
    for root, subdirs, files in os.walk(path):
        root = root + "/" 
        parent_directory = os.path.dirname(root)
        for filename in os.listdir(parent_directory):
            if filename.endswith("file.txt"):
                path = os.path.join(parent_directory, filename)
                target = os.path.join(root, parent_directory + "_" + filename) //I know this is where the issue is...not sure what to do.
                os.rename(path, target)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Using print statements, however, I see that path is set to:

```
/Users/myname/Documents/folder1/folder2/file.txt
```

and target is set to:

```
/Users/myname/Documents/folder1/folder2_file.txt
```

instead of

```
/Users/myname/Documents/folder1/folder2/folder2_file.txt
```

How can I fix this? I've identified the buggy line in my code and I know why it is doing what it is, but I'm not sure how to adjust it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `os.path.basename` to get the last directory from a path string. You can then prepend the filename with it. So switch the line you set `target` to the following:

```
target = os.path.join(path, root + os.path.basename(parent_directory) + "_" + filename)
```